how can i create a shadcn toast in my next js and creates its variants in storybook?
Tech stack : shadcn , tailwind , typescript ,nextjs, storybook
I was able to make static but instead i want it to be dynamic
this is toaster.tsx I am new to the storybook so having difficulty
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';
import { useToast } from '@/components/ui/use-toast/use-toast';
import { Toaster } from '../toaster/toaster';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button/button';

const meta: Meta<typeof Toaster> = {
  component: () => {
    const { toast } = useToast();
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => toast({ type: 'foreground', title: 'hello' })}>
          Go for toast
        </Button>
        <Toaster />
      </div>
    );
  },
  args: {
    color: 'red',
  },
};`your text`

export default meta;

export const Default: StoryObj<typeof Toaster> = {
  args: {},
};

